# Translate the following argument into symbolic form

Tags: notation, logic-translation

Translate the following argument into symbolic form.  State clearly what each of the propositions are

I walk and I cycle and I run. 
If I do not stay at home I cycle or I run. 
I do not cycle therefore I stay at home.

naming the simple
propositions

p: I walk
q: I cycle
r: I run
s: I stay at home

I have tried my hands quite a few times but its not working out . hopefully someone can help

Comment: You should be more specific about what you tried and where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Symbol for and

$\land$

Symbol for or

$\lor$

Symbol for not/negation

$\neg$

Symbol for If A then B/ A implies B /A therefore B

$A \implies B$

Symbol for therefore

$\therefore$

You may use implies in place of therefore if you wish.

Comment: Glad to help. @MohsinSheikh

Answer (score 0):

1. $p \wedge q \wedge r$
2. $\neg s \rightarrow (q \vee r)$
3. $\neg q \rightarrow s$.

I hope this helps. Perhaps there's a different style you're supposed to use.